# Building Qt 5.x from Source with MSYS2 / MinGW 64 - ICU unicode header missing

Tags: qt, sax, mingw-w64

After successfully running the configure script (see [Building Qt 5.8 from source - configure: Unknown command line option '-c++11'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887821/building-qt-5-8-from-source-configure-unknown-command-line-option-c11?noredirect=1#comment70958362_41887821)) I started the build:

```
mingw32-make.exe -j 4
```

But after some time I got following error:

```
In file included from C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/src/xml/dom/qdom.cpp:55:0:
../../../include/QtXml/5.8.1/QtXml/private/qxml_p.h:1:85: fatal error: ../../../../../../../../../../../home/asp/qt5/qtbase/src/xml/sax/qxml_p.h: No such file or directory
 #include "../../../../../../../../../../../home/asp/qt5/qtbase/src/xml/sax/qxml_p.h"
```

I searched for the file and it's where it should be:

```
ls ~/qt5/qtbase/src/xml/sax/
qxml.cpp  qxml.h  qxml_p.h  sax.pri
```

Is this a problem with Qt 5.8.1 or did I forget to set some option? I'll try 5.7, but I don't expect better results.

With 5.7 the configure script doesn't show the success message:

```
Creating qmake...
...........................................................................................Done.
Info: creating stash file C:\msys64\home\asp\qt-build\.qmake.stash
Info: creating super cache file C:\msys64\home\asp\qt-build\.qmake.super
```

With Qt 5.8 there was a message:

```
Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into 'C:\msys64\opt\qt'
```

But maybe this is normal, so I started the build:

```
mingw32-make.exe -j 4
cd qtbase/ && ( test -e Makefile || C:/msys64/home/asp/qt-build/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe -o Makefile C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/qtbase.pro ) && C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile
Info: creating cache file C:\msys64\home\asp\qt-build\qtbase\.qmake.cache
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:31: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:31: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:31: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:31: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:31: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:31: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:31: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:31: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:31: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf:4: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
C:/msys64/home/asp/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf:13: 'prepareRecursiveTarget' is not a recognized test function.
Unknown generator specified: DUMMY
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/msys64/home/asp/qt-build/qtbase'
mingw32-make[1]: Makefile: No such file or directory
mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile'.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/msys64/home/asp/qt-build/qtbase'
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

So 5.7 is no alternative.

I've tries other versions from  [Qt Downloads](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/):

- qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7.tar.gz
- qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0.7z
- qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2.7z
- qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0.7z
- qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1.7z
- qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.7z

All versions fail, because some ICU header from the unicode subfolder couldn't be found. But I observed a strange thing: If I start the failing command manually in the corresponding folder, the output is generated without error! Then I can start make again and repeat this procedure a few files later again. But I can't do the whole build that way...

Comment: did you have any success? I'm now in the same situation but didn't fully get the MINQW way yet ...

Answer (score 1):

Look at our repository how we do building Qt5:
https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-qt5

Comment: Are you willing to explain how that works? The PKGBUILD you refer to seems to import a bunch of dependencies, which I assumed were other packages, but there's no mingw-w64-qt5-base package in that repo.